# If column is greater than "int", appear more than once

Tags: mysql

I've got a table which contains week numbers and id's

```
| id | week |
| 1  |  1   |
| 2  |  2   |
| 3  |  6   |
| 4  |  8   |
```

What I need to do is retrieve based on the value of week. But I also need to return the row more than once if the row is greater than a certain number.

For instance (pseudo),

```
if week > 2
and week > 6

| id | week |
| 2  |  2   |
| 3  |  6   |
| 3  |  6   |
| 4  |  8   |
| 4  |  8   |
```

ID 3 & ID 4 appear twice, because they're greater than both 2 and 6. ID 2 will only appear once because it is only greater than 2.

Unfortunately looped queries are *sort of* out of the question as this query will be return 2k+ rows.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, even if the solution is PHP based.

Comment: Why will it return twice (ID 3,4)? It will return only once even if you use an OR. I am not able to catch your question. What is the end result you require through the query?

Comment: The end result would be to display the week multiple times based on what its greater than, but at the same time whether it exists in another table. I'm currently trying it in a UNION like @Sirko said, but I'm unsure whether this will work or not due to EXISTS and NOT EXISTS further on in the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]Split the query into multiple queries and then merge the result using `UNION`.

The following should give you the result you want.

```
(SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE week > 2)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE week > 6)
```

**edited** included the hint by Lily - thx.

Comment: +1'd your answer due to the nature of it being correct, although I'm not too sure whether it will work in my situation. Currently trying it at the moment, I'll let you know the result.

Comment: @BennyC It doesnt work ... and try **union all** instead of union. It still returns only for id =4 twice. :)

Comment: **Works brilliantly**, just got to further limit it down by further parameters. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Sirko And this gives only for id=4 twice even with UNION ALL rt? Even i am trying ....

Comment: @Lily change the `>` to `>=` to get the exact result OP wanted.

Comment: @Sirko ah.... nice... so change that too to your answer :) added the screenshot to make it more favourable :)